# HttpPost not rendering the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The below mentioned code not redering the page. is there anything need to be added with this.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CompetitiveSnapshotDetails(Object[] comp)
        {
            CompetitiveSnapModel[] compSnapList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CompetitiveSnapModel[]>(comp[0].ToString());
            String[] competitiveDetailHeader = { "State", "Rank", "Terracon Inc Transcations", "Number 1 Firm", "Number 2 Firm", "Number 3 Firm", "Total Transcations" };
            ViewData["CompetitiveDetailHeader"] = competitiveDetailHeader;
            ViewData["CompetitiveDetail"] = compSnapList;
            return View();
        }
```

Call this using ajax

```
$("#com-snap").click(function () {
        var competitiveSnap = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("l_compSnap"));
        var URL = "../Detailpage/CtDetails";
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: { comp: JSON.stringify(competitiveSnap)},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {             
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: no error no output. the same page still there

Comment: And how are you calling this action? Please update your question with further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that in you AJAX code, you are not calling the same action you showed first.
The URL you need to put is more like:

```
"/YourController/CompetitiveSnapshotDetails"
```

The second and more important issue is that your need to grab the html of your view and do something with it.

Your VIEW HTML is in your `data` parameter in your `success` function.

Something like this: `$('#YourContainer').html(data);`